# Animation with jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) for image slider. I am new to jQuery so from the jCarousel documentation I can't figure out how to apply different animation effects.

Say I have one image at a slice, and I want the view image disappear slowly, and simultaneously the next picture appear in the same place.  How can I achieve this effect? Is it a custom animation, that requires to write a new JS function, or it can be done via setting of jCarousel?

Comment: Anything you have tried, would be helpful to guide you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karine, I believe you should use the *easing* configuration property. http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration

Here you can specify the jquery easing effect you want to use (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). If you need something else you can create a custom animation. Here you can see an example http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_easing.html.

Alternatively, you can obtain the desired effect using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function carouselFadeOut(carousel) {
  var clipId = carousel.clip.context.id;
  $('#' + clipId).fadeOut();
}

function carouselFadeIn(carousel) {
  var clipId = carousel.clip.context.id;
  $('#' + clipId).fadeIn();
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({visible : 1, scroll : 1, 

    itemLoadCallback: {
      onBeforeAnimation: carouselFadeOut,
      onAfterAnimation: carouselFadeIn
    }
  });
});
```

Hope it helps, Fabrizio

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use 'easing' property. What values I can pass it to work?

Comment: The easiest way to use _easing_ is through a plugin. For example you could use http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ in your page specifying the function you want to use in the easing jcarousel property.

Comment: I know also about this! But again, I don't know how to use them. (Seems you too :)))) Could you please give a simple example?

Comment: Ok I got the easing plugin working. But none of them does the animation I have pointed out in my question.

Comment: I have modified my original reply. I hope the above code can help you to get what you need. Fabrizio

Comment: Thank you so much Fabrizio Fortino. Honestly I have already used http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ , but consider that I have learned a lot from your reply. Thanks!

Comment: itemLoadCallback exists in JCarousel v.0.2 only